# Customizable components for Sencha

Tags: datagridview, sencha-touch, custom-component

Have spend quite some time to learn Sencha touch, just like an evaluation about the framework. I am creating applications for tablets and not smart phones. I find that there are no built in controls for calendar, accordion, customizable dataView or grid etc. What do you suggest as the best practices or alternatives to get these requirements done? Is it possible to customize all the components in Sencha touch according to my requirement? If I have 16 textboxes, is there any way to get the values of all 16 with one getValue() method? If I have a table, how do I add a click event to each '' and the click should trigger a new page or another table?

These queries comes from the set of requirements that I have to create an application with Sencha for Tablets. The application is a complex one and hence I prefer to move with Sencha, but I need these queries to be addressed to proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google the components you listed for and you will see some components like "calendar", "grid" etc are already available - not with code package but as plugins. Also check Sencha Touch Forum for new plugins.

Check custom plugins [sencha forum here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?58-Sencha-Touch-1.x-Examples-and-Showcases).

Not all the components can be included in the base package - but you can always create separate plugins/custom component for your need. You can make extend most of the components to have your own component.

To get all the textbox values together, give them separate names and put all them in a Form Panel. Then you can retrieve all the values together with form panels [getValues()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-getValues) method. Go through Sencha Blog & API docs and you will learn a lot.